# CloudSearch or CloudQuery to search by 'contains' in CloudBoost

Tags: filter, contains, cloudboost

I need to filter data by substring, I mean, if I have got this data:

```
'John','Markus','james'
```

And i want to look by all elements which contains 'm' it should return:

```
'Markus','james'
```

Or if I filter by 'hn', the results should be:

```
'John'
```

How can I do it using CloudSearch or CloudQuery?

**EDIT:** I have seen wildcard method which seems to fit with my requirements, except for only is allowed a column (string) param. I would need to filter also by columns (array). As in searchOn method.

Comment: Please add necessary language/library tags to improve visibility.

Comment: I would like to add cloudboost tag, but it does not exist in predefined tags and I cannot create them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work I think. did you try it with this :

```
var query = new CB.CloudQuery('TableName');
//then you can:
query.substring('ColName','Text');
//or
query.substring(['ColName1','ColName2'],'Text');
//or
query.substring('ColName',['Text1', 'Text2']);
//or
query.substring(['ColName1','ColName2'],['Text1', 'Text2']);

query.find(callback);
```

Comment: Yes I tried it, but it only search by the whole word. I want to search by substring.

Comment: Oh okay. We need to add regex API. Can you give me a day and I'll build it for you. :)

Comment: I'll also use the substring API which uses regex behind the scenes. :)

Comment: Thanks!, but remember the other requirement: it would be nice to pass a string or an array as a first argument. Same as searchOn.

Comment: We have a new API now in CloudQuery which should do the work. Check the updated answer. :)

Comment: It works perfectly, when also allow array columns I will close this questions.

Comment: Array of columns is now supported!